# Simple Java Plot with x-y data calculated in another class

Tags: java, plot

I'm looking at using http://yuriy-g.github.io/simple-java-plot/ for simple x-y scatter plots.
How can I get the code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // configuring plot options
    Plot plot = Plot.plot(Plot.plotOpts().
            title("Intensity vs. Distance").
            legend(Plot.LegendFormat.BOTTOM)).
        xAxis("mm", Plot.axisOpts().
            range(0, 10)).
        yAxis("I", Plot.axisOpts().
            range(0, 1000)).
        series("Data", Plot.data().
            xy(0, 1000).
            xy(1, 50).
            xy(2, 25),
            Plot.seriesOpts().
                marker(Plot.Marker.DIAMOND).
                markerColor(Color.GREEN).
                color(Color.BLACK));
    plot.save("sample_data", "png");
}
```

to programmatically read in multiple x-y points (i.e. xy(X1, Y2). xy(X2, Y2). ...) from elsewhere. i.e. I have another class that calculates these x-y points and want to pass these to plot them or alternatively call plotting.

From the *Data* class in *Plot.java* it seems to be possible.

P.S. I'm new to Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked out it can be done like this:

```
private static final double[] xvals = new double[4];
private static final double[] yvals = new double[4];

static {
    xvals[0] = 1;
    xvals[1] = 2;
    xvals[2] = 3;
    xvals[3] = 4;
}

static {
    yvals[0] = 1000;
    yvals[1] = 500;
    yvals[2] = 250;
    yvals[3] = 125;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // configuring plot options
    Plot plot = Plot.plot(Plot.plotOpts().
            title("Intensity vs. Distance").
            legend(Plot.LegendFormat.BOTTOM)).
        xAxis("mm", Plot.axisOpts().
            range(0, 10)).
        yAxis("I", Plot.axisOpts().
            range(0, 1000)).
        series("Data", Plot.data().
            xy(xvals, yvals),
            Plot.seriesOpts().
                marker(Plot.Marker.DIAMOND).
                markerColor(Color.GREEN).
                color(Color.BLACK));
    plot.save("sample_data", "png");
}
```